# Compiling a C generated file using Cython

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython, cythonize

I am trying to compile a generated .c file from a .py file using

```
cython --embed -o hello.c hello.py
```

I have a hello.c generated successfully but whenever I try to compile that using gcc

```
gcc -Os -I <python_include_dir> -o hello hello.c -L <python_libs_dir> -lpython3 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

I get lots of compilation errors

```
In file included from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include/Python.h:38,
                 from hello.c:16:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include/pyport.h:601:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  601 | #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
      |  ^~~~~
error: expected expression before ‘int’
15508 |                 __PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT_EXC(int, PY_LONG_LONG, PyLong_AsLongLong(x))
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘zero’
15069 |                 func_type zero = 0;\
note: in expansion of macro ‘__PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT_EXC’
15508 |                 __PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT_EXC(int, PY_LONG_LONG, PyLong_AsLongLong(x))
```

that's a sample of it, I get lot more.

Anyone could suggest any direction I could start digging into?

I am using gcc 11.4.0 from Cygwin, and Python 3.11.2

EDITED: Added first couple of error showing up

Comment: The first few error messages are usually the most helpful (I suspect you've taken a random selection from the middle). My guess would be you haven't got the include for Python.h right, but you don't show enough to know that

Comment: You are right, I added a couple from the end of the output feed, I edited and added the first two errors that show up

Comment: I suspect it's a mismatch between Python for Windows (which is designed to be compiled with MSVC) and Cygwin (which is designed to be Linux-like). You probably either need to use MSVC or use a version of Python specifically built for Cygwin.